# SSMS results as a clickable link

Tags: hyperlink, ssms

I am fairly new to SQL and I have looked around to see if i could find a way to do this if it is possible

Here is my SQL query text:

```
SELECT *, 
CONCAT('https://domain:8080/analyzer?sipid=',SIPCallId,'&cmd=GetAnswerWAV') 'FaxScope: Inbound Audio (WAV) Link',
```

The result:

https://domain:8080/analyzer?sipid=b38f9368905eadc713c42d5894512203898221635dac1a50e70-0084-7302&cmd=GetAnswerWAV

In the SQL Query results, I have to copy/paste the url into a web browser to get the data this link should provide.

Is this possible to have the SQL result be a clickable link itself?

Comment: Is this is a question about the SQL client you're using? If so, you might have more luck if you ask this question on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: I am new here so please forgive me. 
Can you direct me to where I should post this at?

Thank you

Comment: Sure! Try serverfault.com and/or superuser.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm not certain if it's possible to have the results window push through to a browser window, you can declare the result of your query to be `for xml path`. this will push the URL into a new session in the query window from which you should be able to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click through to the embedded SSMS browser.

```
declare @url varchar( 255 )

select @url = 'http://www.google.com' -- your query here

select @url for xml path
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using SSMS Boost plugin: [Results Grid data Visualizers](https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-results-grid-visualizers-feature)

Then you could select appropriate application(web browser) and allow for opening a new webpage.