# Display table with hyperlink SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to display all table with hyperlink

```
ID  TYPE LINK

1   A    http://www.google.com

2   B    http://www.yahoo.com
```

I found solution how to convert text to clickable hyperlink but I still don't know how to display all table.

[SSMS results as a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703540/ssms-results-as-a-clickable-link/52478612#52478612)

I use SQL Server 2016.

Thanks in advance
Mortal

Comment: I can't see why you'd really want to achieve this. SSMS is a development/administration tool, so your users are unlikely to be using this. If you're passing to a presentation layer, the. You should be handling the creation of a hyperlink there, not in the SQL. Seems like an xy Question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, TYPE VARCHAR(50), Link VARCHAR(255))
```

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,'A','http://www.google.com')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2,'B','http://www.yahoo.com')

SELECT ID,TYPE,Link  FROM @Table for xml PATH

Comment: When I do it this way I see everything in one row and I wolud like to see seperate column in which one of them will be hyperlink