# How to produce a clickable link in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I created a table:

```
create table data  
(
    description nvarchar(100),
    url varchar(500)
)
```

Then I insert data:

```
INSERT INTO data (description, url)
VALUES ('google', 'https://www.google.com'),
       ('yahoo', 'https://www.yahoo.com'),
       ('baidu', 'https://www.baidu.com')
```

I want to get a clickable url when executing:

```
select url 
from data 
where description = 'google'
```

In other words, when I click the url returned, a chrome will be opened and go to google site.

I found that there is a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703540/ssms-results-as-a-clickable-link) but it requires user to click twice.

What should I do?

Comment: This is not something you can do in SSMS.

Comment: Any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

The one that succeed to me is setting the data type of the url as xml so that it is clickable then you will get a new query window and there if you click the url with CTRL+K then the url will pop in the sql server window. For url the most appropriate data type would Varchar with preferred length but unfortunately that is not clickable within SSMS.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can check the following URL, 
basically you can click in query editor or you can set and there are few more alternatives here,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c78549d-0aa2-4fed-acab-51ad11cb59a4/is-url-clickable-somewhere-in-ssms?forum=transactsql

Comment: Can I open the url in chrome?

Comment: check the comment, you can set xml data type and do that

Comment: I arrived the step you mentioned above, but I cannot get the method to use chrome to open chrome

Comment: I think that's because your default browser is not chrome. Can you change the default browser of your pc as chrome and try.

Comment: Which browser it's opening from, Internet explorer ?

Comment: It just opened the url inside SSMS, not in chrome.